# How to reload fragment when the back button is hit

Tags: android

how to reload a fragment when back button is pressed. I have handled the back button code, i am getting to the place where in the fragment needs to be reloaded, but i am failing in reloading the fragments.

I need my changes to be visible on screen, so i should reload. any simple steps/?

Answer (score 0):

Override [Fragment.onResume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onResume%28%29) and update your Fragment there according to the changes.